# Windows form application timertick problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I used hold and release timer tick with modbus protocol.So It reads every second

1. Timer Interval : 1000
2. Enabled : True

I'm having a freezing problem. How can I fix it?

Please Help Me.

---

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ModBus1.Send_Device(Read, temperatureStartAddress, (ushort)TemperatureValueQnty, temperatureValue);
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        ModBus1.Send_Device(Read, temperatureStartAddress, (ushort)TemperatureValueQnty, temperatureValue);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
       
        if (SettingsTab.Enabled == true)
        {
            moduleTextBox.Text = temperatureValue[0].ToString();
            moduleTextBox2.Text = temperatureValue[1].ToString();
            moduleTextBox3.Text = temperatureValue[2].ToString();
            moduleTextBox4.Text = temperatureValue[3].ToString();
            moduleTextBox5.Text = temperatureValue[4].ToString();
            moduleTextBox6.Text = temperatureValue[5].ToString();
            moduleTextBox7.Text = temperatureValue[6].ToString();
            moduleTextBox8.Text = temperatureValue[7].ToString();
            moduleTextBox9.Text = temperatureValue[8].ToString();
            moduleTextBox10.Text = temperatureValue[9].ToString();
            moduleTextBox11.Text = temperatureValue[10].ToString();
            moduleTextBox12.Text = temperatureValue[11].ToString();
        }
}
```

Comment: On which line is it freezing? Adding delays within a timer-based method is not a good idea since overrides might occur

Comment: I have to add delay

Comment: Maybe you could use `async` `await` to instead `Thread.Sleep();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments, the real question is:

**Method ModBus1.Send has a parameter temperatureValue which is an int[]. I want to convert the filled data to a `List<double>`**

I wonder how you know how long you should make your array of integers, but let's assume you do know the length:

```
int temperatureValueCount = ...; // expected number of temperature values
int[] temperatureValues = new int[temperatureValueCount];
ModBus1.Send_Device(Read, temperatureStartAddress,
    (ushort)TemperatureValueQnty, 
    temperatureValues);

// temperatureValues is now filled with integers
// convert this to a List<double> using LINQ:
List<double> returnValue = temperatureValues.Cast<double>().ToList();
```

Or if you don't like LINQ:

```
List<double> returnValue = new List<double>(temperatureValues.Length);
foreach (int temperatureValue in temperatureValues)
    returnValue.Add((double)temperatureValue);
```

**Back to the original question**

> I'm having a freezing problem.

If you use your user interface thread to do some lengthy processing, then during this processing your user interface is not responsive.

Nowadays there are two often used methods to prevent this:

- Start a different thread to do this lengthy calculation
- If your calculation is mostly waiting idly for another process, like waiting for a file to be written, a database query to be executed, or waiting for information of the internet, or in your case: waiting until some time has passed: use async-await.

> async await is only useful if your thread will be waiting idly for something else.

If your thread has to do some heavy calculations, so if it will be really busy, consider to start a different thread to do the calculations. This way your user interface thread will be free to handle operator requests.

If you are not familiar with async-await, [this interview with Eric Lippert](https://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) really helped me to understand async-await. Search somewhere in the middle for async await.

Eric Lippert compares async await with a cook who has to make breakfast. He could start boiling water for the tea, wait until the water boils and make the tea. Then he puts bread in the toaster and wait idly until the bread is toasted. After that he boils some eggs, and waits idly until the eggs are finished.

You see all the idly waits for other processes. It would be much more efficient to put on the kettle for the tea, start toasting the bread and boiling the eggs. The task that finishes first continues first.

Async-await is similar: instead of waiting until the file has been written, or the database query returns data, your thread looks around to see if he can do something else, like responding to user input.

To use async await you'll have to change your code slightly.

- Every method that uses async-await, must be declared async
- Every async method should return `Task<TResult>` instead of `TResult` and `Task` instead of `void`
- Only exception: event handlers (like button clicked), they return void.
- Inside your async method, call other async methods and await for them to finish. In fact, your compiler will warn you if you forget to await.
- If you don't need the results of the await immediately, don't await yet, continue processing until you need the result of the async method.
- Make sure that every task has been awaited before you return from the async method, even if you don't need the result. If you don't await, you don't know when the task is finished, and thus will never know if you can safely destruct your class.
- Just a convention: async method names have Async postfix. So you can keep them next to the non-async version: `TextWriter.Write` and `TextWriter.WriteAsync`.

.

```
async Task<int> CalculateOrderTotalAsync(int orderId)
{
    Task<int> taskFetchOrderTotal = dbContext.OrderLines
        .Where(orderLine => orderLine.OrderId == orderId)
        .Select(orderLine => orderLine.Price)
        .SumAsync();

    // because you didn't await, you are free to do some other processing:
    DoSomethingElse();

    // now you need the result of the database query:
    int orderTotal = await taskFetchOrderTotal();
    return orderTotal;
 }
```

While the database management system is executing the query, your thread is free to do something else. When it needs the results, it starts awaiting. If the database query is finished, it continues. If not, the thread doesn't wait idly, but goes up the call stack to execute other statements, until it sees an await, goes up the call stack again, etc.

Quite often, your task has noting else to do. In that case you'll see the await immediately before the call:

```
async Task SaveTextAsync(string fileName, string text)
{
    using (var textWriter = File.CreateText(fileName))
    {
        await textWriter.WriteLineAsync(text);
    }
}
```

### Back to your question

Your thread is mostly waiting idly, in your Sleep methods. There is an async method to await some time: [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay). If you use that in an async method your UI will be responsive.

```
private async Task<List<double> ReadTemperatureValuesAsync()
{
    List<double> temperaturValues = new List<double>();

    // tell the modbus to start reading the temperatures:
    ModBus1.Send_Device(Read, temperatureStartAddress, (ushort)TemperatureValueQnty, temperatureValues);

    // await 250 msec. The UI will be responsive
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.250));

    // communicate with the modbus again. and await again:
    ModBus1.Send_Device(Read, temperatureStartAddress, (ushort)TemperatureValueQnty, temperatureValues);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMiliSeconds(50);

    return temperatureValues;
}
```

You need a method to Display the Temperature values. This procedure has no idly wait. So no await needed:

```
private void DisplayMeasuredTemperatures(List<double> measuredTemperatures)
{
    moduleTextBox.Text = temperatureValue[0].ToString();
    moduleTextBox2.Text = temperatureValue[1].ToString();
    ...
}
```

Put it all together: async Measure and display the results:

```
private async Task MeasureAndDisplayTemperaturesAsync()
{
    List<double> measuredTemperatures = await this.ReadTemperatureValuesAsync();
    if (SettingsTab.Enabled)
    {
        DisplayMeasuredTemperatures(measuredTemperatures);
    }
}
```

Finally your timer tick method. This is an event handler: return void instead of Task:

```
private async void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await MeasureAndDisplayTemperaturesAsync();
}
```

If you want to call it after a button click:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await MeasureAndDisplayTemperaturesAsync();
}
```

### Long calculations

If your method doesn't have to wait for another process, but has some long calculations to do, think of starting a Task, and await for it to finish.

```
private int SomeLongCalculations(Customer customer)
{
     int result = 0;
     for (long i=0; i<10000000000000000000000; ++i)
     {
         ... // something with Customer and i
     }
     return result;
}

private async Task<int> CalculateAsync(Customer customer)
{
    int calculationResult = await Task.Run(() => this.SomeLongCalculations(customer);
    return calculationResult;
}
```

Comment: It is a great expression. I will try it, I am very happy now.

Comment: Hey Harald Coppoolse.I got an error.Modbus1.Send_Device(byte comman,ushort Address,ushort Package,int[] values).So tempreture values should be int[] but.We did List<int>.

Comment: Harald.I need your help.

Comment: If you need an array of integers instead of a list of integers, Then why not change `List<int>` into `int[...]`? Surely you did try this, didn't you?

Comment: I have to return in the async Task<List<int>> ReadTemperatureValuesAsync() method.But if i do List<int> into int[].Method does not return.

Comment: Who says that you have to return `Task<List<int>>`? Why not change that to `Task<int[]>`? If your project manager insists that you should return a List, then tell him that `Modbus1.Send` should be changed such, that it returns a List. If you can't agree on that: convert the returned `int[]` into a List. That would be inefficient. If you don't know how to convert an `int[]` into a `List<int>`, then consider to spend some time learning C# and LINQ

Comment: Oh okay.Thanks for all Harald Coppoolse.